# How to write an index block using two columns in pandas' record-linkage?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, record-linkage

I want to make pairs of `index` on the condition that the info of two `columns` of the compared database are equal. Can this be implemented using the `index` class of record linkage?

```
# dfg and dfm are databases that both contain the columns 'N_name' and 'N_cp'
import recordlinkage as rl

indexer_try = rl.Index()
indexer_try.block('N_name','N_name','N_cp','N_cp')
candidate_links = indexer_try.index(dfg, dfm)
```

I expected the class to create the multiindex that contains indexes that match these criterion.

Instead I got, **init**() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to include the columns as an array

```
# Indexation step
import recordlinkage as rl

indexer = rl.Index()
indexer.block(['N_name'],['N_name']) # 25k
indexer.block(['N_address', 'N_cp'],['N_address','N_cp']) #211k
indexer.block('latlng', 'latlng') # 320k
candidate_links = indexer.index(dfg, dfm)
```